# Virtual ClearableFileInput with clear select box

Tags: django

I have a *virtual* form field that I would like to give an initial value, so the clear select box appears, but setting `initial` etc doesn't do it.

How can I set make the clear box appear?

```
thumbnail_custom = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(), required=False)
```

I've looked into how Django handles [ClearableFileInput](https://github.com/django/django/blob/a5de0df58b5431b25a3246a57432db73843be87f/django/forms/widgets.py#L373), but I miss knowledge of how to assign the needed parameters.

I have also tried this approach:

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
ff = SimpleUploadedFile('best_file_eva.txt', 'these are the file contents!')

self.fields['thumbnail_custom'] = forms.CharField(
    required=False,
    widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(),
    initial=ff
)
```

Comment: What are you passing in as your initial value?

Comment: I tried with the path. Do you know what I should provide?

Comment: Some sort of File object, with a url attribute, though I'm not sure it will work as you expect.